# CSS: Where is a tag being applied?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website for a volunteering organisation whose parent organisation ordered us to implement a rebranding and gave us several css sheets.

My problem is this:

A page is structured like so:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>blah</p>
<p>blah</p>
<p>blah</p>
```

From what Firebug tells me, the first paragraph is being given a p.intro property that is making it larger. What tool can I use to discover where the tag is being applied? There is nothing that specifies any css tags in the page.

Kind Thanks!

Comment: Is your question "My HTML doesn't include a class attribute, but when I inspect the DOM one has been added. How can I find out where it is coming from?"

Comment: Yes that's it exactly. I'm not familiar with the proper terminology for this.

Comment: I feel that it should be doable with Firebug but I cannot get it. The "Break on attribute change" feature in the HTML panel persists between page loads but doesn't catch onload changes :-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the HTML you are providing is what comes out of "View > Source" (so it isn't being mangled by any server side processing), then it is almost certainly coming from JavaScript.

Search through all the JS files for mention of "intro" and you'll probably track it down. If that fails, expand the search for the HTML files in case you have embedded JS.

Comment: You should be able to check if it's caused by Javascript before you go searching through the files. Turn off javscript and see if it still happens. (Using the web developer toolbar for firefox is the easiest way)